# Error closing workbook (Subscript out of range)

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to close a specific workbook using the following code:

```
Workbooks("C:\Users\vin.xls").Close
```

But I am getting the error: subscript out of range. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Workbooks("vin.xls").Close` instead.

The `Workbooks` collection isn't (normally) indexed by the full file name, including the path. You get the `subscript out of range` error if an item does not exist in the collection.

Comment: Perfect. Another doubt. The file that i want to close will be in a common hard drive. So if another user has opened the file in his system, then if i execute this code, will it work??

Comment: It will always work if the user has the file open, assuming the network is still available at the point of close.

Comment: Since `Workbooks.Close` doesn't include saving, this will always work. If you have opened a protected copy of an already open Workbook (and want to save it), a dialogue will open.